# ESlint complaining about useless constructor

Tags: typescript, eslint

I'm getting ESlint error in this file

**Bar.ts:**

```
class Bar {
  constructor(public foo: string) {}

  hello(): string {
    return this.foo;
  }
}

export default Bar;
```

my eslint config:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es2020": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "airbnb/base",
    "eslint-config-prettier"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 11
  },
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin", "eslint-plugin-prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "no-unused-vars": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires": "warn",
    "func-names": "off",
    "no-underscore-dangle": "off",
    "class-methods-use-this": "off"
  },
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.ts"],
      "excludedFiles": ["*.js"],
      "rules": {
        "@typescript/no-var-requires": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Eslint error on Bar.ts:

```
Useless constructor. eslint(no-useless-constructor)
```

If you are curious why my eslint config looks the way it is, it's because I'm trying to setup a project with both JS and TS files, and make ESLint work for each type of the file respectively.

What do I need to change in my ESLint config to make it not complaining about totally relevant code?

Comment: You need to move the typescript-eslint extends to the end of the array, I think, so they override the inapplicable rules from earlier options. Or just disable the rule yourself in the rules map for the TS overrides.

Comment: A side note: if you can see that something is completely messed up in my eslint config, please let me know. I'm a complete profane in eslint and this is my first try of getting it to work

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you for the quick answer. If I got you right I tried to move the `extends` block to end of the file. But it din't helped (I also tried to reload a session after this). Please let me know if I got your idea right. Also disabling the rule is not the option, since currently eslint just treating my ts file as a js which can be a huge issue in the future

Comment: No, you didn't get me right; the order of keys in an object doesn't matter at all. Try moving the TS-ESLint-specific *entries* in the extends array (order does matter in arrays) to after whatever sets that rule (probably airbnb/base).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes. The airbnb/base was the issue. Now it's pretty clear that I had to use `airbnb-typescript/base` instead. Can you please post the answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: It sounds like my suggestion wasn't actually the solution - you can write up your own answer if you've figured it out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe I have figured out that that the issue was inside the `extends` block. The `airbnb/base` in particular which is meant for js files.
I had to replace it with `airbnb-typescript/base` and then the other issue popped up which was even more critical:

To use airbnb-typescript/base I had to:

1. Generate the tsconfig (I haven't generated it yet, since currently my primary goal is to get ESlint to work more or less properly and completetly forgot about some basic things)
2. Add a `project` option in my `parserOptions` which points to the `tsconfig`

Somebody who is familiar with the TS and ESlint probably has noticed from the very beginning that my eslint config was missing that option.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing a lot of things here and this is not the last question about this topic, but for now the error is gone and I can move forward.

Answer (score 1):

**For stop this error**

write this on .eslintrc file

```
"rules": {
    "no-useless-constructor": 0,
}
```